# Is it possible to create a app where you can choose between Metro and WPF GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I'm just wondering if it's possible to create a application with 2 GUI layers. One just standard WPF GUI and one metro GUI for windows tablets. The basic idea is that you can tell to your app in which mode it should run. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score -1):

If those 2 GUI Layers can be just themes then Yes you can. There are many extensions for Visual Studio to do this. I have used Telerik UI controls for winforms. Telerik also provides UI controls for WPF. You can create a Project in WPF and then you can choose a metro theme which Telerik provides. This way your application will have 2 GUI layers. You can set the theme at the runtime doing this:

```
private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ThemeName = telerikMetroTheme1.ThemeName;
}
```

I have done this at the FormLoad event but you can do this on any event or a button. This way you can also let the user chose between a different set of themes. You can also define your own themes and use them using RadThemeManager.

Comment: And will that __run under__ Metro or just look like Metro?

Comment: Thank you. The Telerik WPF Metro controls http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx seem to just act like Metro and support touch. It's quite weird that Microsoft didn't implement a way to to have a application that runs in Metro and just standard WPF. If I would like to support windows 7 and older versions of windows, it just seems like I have to write 2 different applications. IMHO its a complete overkill and not the worth doing this.

Comment: Select it as the answer if it answers your question, or up vote it if it was helpful.

Comment: Well it is helpful. But I actually do not want my app to just act like metro. It should be Metro. I'm still searching for more informations on the internet.

Comment: I do not think it is possible the reason being the libraries. A Metro style app must use references to another .NETCore or Portable Library binary only... It can not reference a full .NET library as compared to WPF or other windows applications because the Metro profile is not that large (and would fail store certification).
You will have to create a portable version of the library you want.